# Is there a way to Decrease load time for data in MVC App

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, ado.net

I have a database with 17000 records. I want to implement a search functionality search that it makes use of FirsorDefault(). At the moment it is pulling all records first within the first load then again pulling all on search.

I am using an SQL query (Not a fan of EF :-)).

Below is my controller code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<PensionMembers> PensionMembers()
    {
        var ind = new List<PensionMembers>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("PENSION")))
        {
            var Query1 = "select * from member INNER JOIN Fund ON Fund.Fund_Number = Member.Fund";
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new(Query1, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                PensionMembers pm = new()
                {
                    Employee_number = reader["Employee_number"].ToString(),
                    First_Name = reader["First_Name"].ToString(),
                    Other_Names = reader["Other_Names"].ToString(),
                    Surname = reader["Surname"].ToString(),
                    Name = reader["Name"].ToString() //Fund Name
                };
                ind.Add(pm);
            }
        }
        return ind;
    }
```

The search parameter in this case is the 'Surname' which is implemented in the view below:

```
            @Html.TextBox("search")
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    Search
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you really want to **increase** the load time?

Comment: absolutely no idea what the question is here

Comment: If your asking about increasing the HTTP timeout then all browsers will implement a maximum value for this that you can't control. Your issue here is your inefficient code, not HTTP

Comment: `select top 1 ...`. Remove `List`. Read only one record from DB: `if (reader.Read()) ... return pm;`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I meant to decrease the time it takes to load

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ```if (reader.Read())..``` only leads to a stack overflow

Comment: You mentioned `FirstOrDefault`. So you want to return only one value?

Comment: Yes, upon search of that value. ```SELECT TOP 1``` will not work in this case

Comment: @Nickson 1) you haven't asked a question yet. 2) your code won't perform *any* better than EF or Dapper. In fact, it probably performs worse than either because it uses a `List` without a capacity, leading to frequent reallocations. The only way to speed up the query itself is to make sure the JOIN columns are indexed. To improve the code, you can replace it Dapper and eg: `return connection.Query< PensionMembers>(sql);` and change the signature to `IEnumerable<PensionMembers>`. This way you won't have to load everything in memory before returning. ASP.NET can work with `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: To improve *scaleability* you can use `async/await` so waiting for a database response won't freeze the request thread, allowing it to serve other requests. This won't improve a single request's performance though

Comment: As for *searching*, 1) you *can't* search all fields at once, you need to specify the fields to search and 2) you should modify your query and add a WHERE clause. You wouldn't have to do that if you used EF Core and LINQ. With ADO.NET or Dapper you have to add `WHERE thatField=@search` and pass the value as a parameter. Eg, using Dapper `Query<PensionMembers>(".... WHERE thatField=@search",new {search=searchText});`. To search for values that start with a term you need to use `LIKE @search` instead of `=@search` and append `%` to the term. The server can use indexes to find eg `John%`

Comment: Searching for other patterns forces the server to scan all tables because indexes can't be used. If you want to search for words, you can use [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) indexes and operators like `CONTAINS`, `FORMSOF` and `NEAR`, to perform google-like searches

Comment: Finally, *don't* load 17K rows if you want to display them to a user. No screen can display 17K rows at a time and generating a 17K-row grid will slow down rendering a *lot*. Use paging and only send a page of results at a time, eg 25-50 rows. Most grid controls use virtualization to *hide* this and give the impression of infinite scrolling. Behind the scenes though, they just retrieve the next few lines when you scroll down to give the impression of smooth scrolling